# Selenium server not responding

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

My setup is like this :

1. Latest Selenium server
2. Latest Phpunit and Selenium plugin
3. Firefox 3.6 (NO plugins is installed even not Selenium IDE)

ok finally my code is like this:

```
<?php
class TestLogin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost');
        $this->prepareSession();
        $this->url('http://localhost');
    }

    public function testSignupFormFor()
    {
         $this->url('http://localhost/ci/index.php/signup/signupController/signup');

         $div = $this->byCssSelector('div#signupFormId');
         $form =$this->byCssSelector('div#signupFormId>form');
         $userObj = $this->byName("userName");

         $userName = $userObj->value('root');   -----> Server hangs here

         $this->assertEquals('root',$userName);
?>
```

When I run the code with phpunit filename.php,
then it opens firefox and hangs with message

When I saw logs of server its like this

```
16:55:36.608 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 2 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebEleme
nt@8e7c2cfc, [r, o, o, t]] at URL: /session/b0da54ee-6029-4ff6-b0b7-2d9b44cbb81c/element/2/value)
16:56:36.631 INFO - Executing: [delete session: b0da54ee-6029-4ff6-b0b7-2d9b44cbb81c] at URL: /session/b0da54ee-6029-4ff
6-b0b7-2d9b44cbb81c)
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Firefox has reached version 20.0.1 now, Are you sure the Selenium version you're using is compatible with your firefox? I almost sure there are some updates related to web driver

Comment: Thanks, Somewhere I read RC does work with only 3.* version browsers .. thats why I installed this pitty browser. Well thanks my problem is resolved. Instead of Selenium2, I am using Selenium interface only :)